# How to load html file stored inside SD card in the web view

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have an html file  in  /mnt/sdcard/packagename/files/something.html path. Now I want to load this file into the webview.

When I surfed for this, I heard something about content provider, but still not cleared exactly how to do it.

Any answer?

Thanks in advance,

Tejaswi Marakini

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            Log.d(TAG, "No SDCARD");
} else {
webComp.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/packagename/files/something.html");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/packagename/files/something.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check here: http://www.anddev.org/read_a_txt_file_from_sd_card_in_a_real_device-t6619.html

The methodology is same for html. Loading files from external storage has nothing to do with the content provider.

Hope this helps!