# Out of memory when loading a large picture (5 MB) or GIFs to WebView

Tags: java, android

I don't want to use `WebView.loadUrl(String url)` because I want to be able to load the image when there is no Internet connection.

Right now, I have this helper function for downloading:

```
public static byte[] downloadBinaryContent(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection hcon = getConnection(url);
    if (hcon == null)
        return null;
    try {
        InputStream is = hcon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(8192);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        CacheHandler.writeBinary(url, baf.toByteArray()); // keep it for offline use
        return baf.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Download Binary Failed", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is for displaying (I could use ImageView but I also want to display GIFs easily):

```
        final WebView web = (WebView) opView.findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                String url_wiki = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Snake_River_%285mb%29.jpg";
                byte[] binary_content = getBinaryContent(url_wiki);
                final String b64Image = Base64.encodeToString(binary_content, Base64.DEFAULT);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        web.loadData(b64Image, "image/jpeg", "base64");
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
```

The function `getBinaryContent()` called here basically checks for cached files, and if not then it will call `downloadBinaryContent()` to download it.

These works fine if I replace the URL to a smaller picture, but fails when it's too big. I suspect the cause of the problem is I'm loading all the byte[] and encoding them to a String in the memory. But how can I avoid this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @user184994 Thanks, but that is mostly talking about scaling the dimension of a bitmap. The main problem I have right now is actually regarding GIFs (that's why I used WebView rather than ImageView actually).

Comment: the only thing I can tell you is not to display 5mb photo its absurd loading that what if you have 4 of those then requesting large heap will not be a solution either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to work around the memory issue with `String`s by caching images as files on external storage, then pointing the `WebView` [directly to those files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7805127).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your Manifest, in the `<Application>` tag.

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

This will request a larger heap space for you app to work with.

Documentation located [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap).

You have specified that 'it fails', but fail to provide any supporting evidence of the fail. The above solution is assuming that you are running into an OutOfMemmory exception when working with large Bitmaps, as is usually the case. If the above fails to fix your problem, please provide a more detaild explanation of 'it fails', and provide logcat logs if applicable.

Comment: Nowhere in the code `Bitmap` instances appear to be created. This is really a memory issue due to the `String` class, as already explained in the question, similar to others already documented in various SO pages.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli I agree, also I would rather not use large heap and instead focus on reducing overall memory usage for improved performance.

Comment: Suit yourself. An app using a 5Mb image that is given 5Mb of heap space will fail 100% of the time regardless of what you do for memory management

Comment: @MattClark I did what Giulio suggested and it works for now. I'll also add the large heap request as a fail-safe. Thank you for your suggestion, and have an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with large image, I would recommend a library, which solves this problem and provides caching. It’s
[Picasso from Square](http://square.github.io/picasso/) Hope this helps to solve your issue.